# React TypeError in bundling npm package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, material-ui, esbuild

I'm creating an NPM package using React, Redux, and Material JS. This package will be added to multiple react applications. I'm using esbuild as the bundler.

This is the error I receive:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')

Here is the Esbuild `js` file:

```
const { build } = require("esbuild");
const { dependencies } = require("./package.json");

const entryFile = "src/index.tsx";
const shared = {
  bundle: true,
  entryPoints: [entryFile],
  external: Object.keys(dependencies),
  logLevel: "info",
  minify: true,
  sourcemap: true,
};

build({
  ...shared,
  format: "esm",
  outfile: "./dist/index.esm.js",
  target: ["esnext", "node12.22.0"],
});

build({
  ...shared,
  format: "cjs",
  outfile: "./dist/index.cjs.js",
  target: ["esnext", "node12.22.0"],
});
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react_component_library",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.cjs.js",
  "module": "dist/index.esm.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run clean && node build.js && tsc --emitDeclarationOnly --outDir dist",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "dev": "node serve.js",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "chokidar": "^3.5.3",
    "esbuild": "^0.17.19",
    "esbuild-plugin-external-global": "^1.0.1",
    "live-server": "^1.2.2",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "11.11.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "5.13.3",
    "@mui/system": "5.13.2",
    "@types/react": "18.2.8",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.4",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

This fails when I import it into another React app:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

interface AppProps {
  name: string;
}

const App: React.FC<AppProps> = ({ name }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hello, there");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello {name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Any ideas? Thank you!